# Refine/Restructure data from Mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Im using NodeJs, MongoDB Native 2.0+

The following query fetch one client document containing arrays of embedded staff and services.

```js
db.collection('clients').findOne({_id: sessId}, {"services._id": 1, "staff": {$elemMatch: {_id: reqId}}}, callback)
```

Return a result like this:

```js
{
  _id: "5422c33675d96d581e09e4ca",
  staff:[
    {
      name: "Anders"
      _id: "5458d0aa69d6f72418969428"
      // More fields not relevant to the question...
    }
  ],
  services: [
    {
      _id: "54578da02b1c54e40fc3d7c6"
    },
    {
      _id: "54578da42b1c54e40fc3d7c7"
    },
    {
      _id: "54578da92b1c54e40fc3d7c9"
    }
  ]
}
```

*Note that each embedded object in `services` actually contains several fields, but `_id` is the only field returned by means of the projection of the query.*

From this returned data I start by "pluck" all id's from `services` and save them in an array later used for validation. This is by no means a difficult operation... but I'm curious...  Is there an easy way to do some kind of aggregation instead of `find`, to get an array of already plucked objectId's directly from the DB. Something like this:

```js
{
  _id: "5422c33675d96d581e09e4ca",
  staff:[
    {
      name: "Anders"
      _id: "5458d0aa69d6f72418969428"
      // More fields not relevant to the question...
    }
  ],
  services: [
    "54578da02b1c54e40fc3d7c6",
    "54578da42b1c54e40fc3d7c7",
    "54578da92b1c54e40fc3d7c9"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is to first,

`$unwind` the document based on the `staff` field, this is done to
select the intended `staff`. This step is required due to the
unavailability of the `$elemMatch` operator in the `aggregation`
framework.

There is an open ticket here: [Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14876?jql=text%20~%20%22%24elemMatch%20aggregation%22)

Once the document with the correct `staff` is selected, `$unwind`, based on `$services`.
The `$group`, together `$push`ing all the `services _id` together in an array.

This is then followed by a `$project` operator, to show the intended fields.

```
db.clients.aggregate([
{$match:{"_id":sessId}},
{$unwind:"$staff"},
{$match:{"staff._id":reqId}},
{$unwind:"$services"},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id","services_id":{$push:"$services._id"},"staff":{$first:"$staff"}}},
{$project:{"services_id":1,"staff":1}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought this should be possible. But the aggregation seems a bit more complex than my client side refinement... so I think Ill stick to that :)